# Add a list in an existing JSON value

Tags: c#, json.net

So I have below call to a method where my argument is a json string of this type

```
var jsonWithSearchData = await querySearchData(jsonOut);
```

jsonOut ->

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "_hash": null,
            "kind": "ENY",
            "id": "t123",
            "payload": {
                "r:attributes": {
                    "lok:934": "@0|I"
                    
                },
                "r:relations": {
                    "lok:1445": "15318",
                    "lok:8538": "08562"
                    
                },
                "r:searchData": "",
                "r:type": [
                    "5085"
                ]
            },
            "type": "EQT",
            "version": "d06"
        }
    }
]
```

The `querySearchData()` returns me two list something like this :`["P123","P124","P987"]` and `["Ba123","KO817","Daaa112"]`

I want to add this list in my `r:searchData` key above. The key inside my `searchData` i.e. `r:Porelation` and `ClassA` and `ClassB` remains static. So I would like my `searchData` in my input Json to finally become something like this.

```
"r:searchData": { 
    "r:Porelation":{
       "ClassA": ["P123","P124","P987"],
       "ClassB": ["Ba123","KO817","Daaa112"]
    }
},
```

How can I do this? What I tried:

```
JArray jfinObject = JArray.Parse(jobjects);
jfinObject["r:searchData"]["r:relations"]["ClassA"] = JArray.Parse(ListofCode.ToString());
```

And I get below error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
> Newtonsoft.Json: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value:
> "r:searchData". Int32 array index expected.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: And, exactly, what is your problem? Serialize/deserialize, data structure?

Comment: i started with this jObject["r:searchData"]["r:Porelation"]["ClassA"] = JObject.Parse(mylist)

Comment: problem is how do I add it inside Search Data

Comment: Updated the code with i tried and the error received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can add a node/object/array to existing json.

One option is to use [Linq-to-Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm#CreatingLINQ) to build up the correct model.
Assuming you have the json string described in your question, the below code will add your desired json to the `r:searchData` node:

```
var arr = JArray.Parse(json);  // the json string
var payloadNode = arr[0]["data"]["payload"];

// use linq-to-json to create the correct object
var objectToAdd = new JObject(
                      new JProperty("r:Porelation", 
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("r:ClassA", array1), 
                            new JProperty("r:ClassB", array2))));

payloadNode["r:searchData"] = objectToAdd;
```

where `array1` and `array2` above could come from a linq query (or just standard arrays).

```
// Output: 
{
  "data": {
    "_hash": null,
    "kind": "ENY",
    "id": "t123",
    "payload": {
      "r:attributes": {
        "lok:934": "@0|I"
      },
      "r:relations": {
        "lok:1445": "15318",
        "lok:8538": "08562"
      },
      "r:searchData": {
        "r:Porelation": {
          "r:ClassA": [
            "P123",
            "P456"
          ],
          "r:ClassB": [
            "Ba123",
            "Ba456"
          ]
        }
      },
      "r:type": [
        "5085"
      ]
    },
    "type": "EQT",
    "version": "d06"
  }
}
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JwWpR8)

---

Another option is to create the json from an object, which could be achieved using `JToken.FromObject()`. However, this will only work if you have property names which are also valid for C# properties. So, this won't work for your desired property names as they contain invalid characters for C# properties, but it might help someone else:

```
// create JToken with required data using anonymous type
var porelation = JToken.FromObject(new 
{ 
    ClassA = new[] { "P123", "P456" },   // replace with your arrays here
    ClassB = new[] { "Ba123", "Ba456" }  // and here
});

// create JObject and add to original array
var newObjectToAdd = new JObject(new JProperty("r:Porelation", porelation));
payloadNode["r:searchData"] = newObjectToAdd;
```

Comment: works, one small issue, instead of classA and ClassB I have key as "r:ClassA" and "r:ClassB". If I replace ClassA and ClassB with r:ClassA and r:ClassB, I get error saying ClassA does not exist. How can I fix this. the key name of ClassA is actually r:ClassA